# Refresh morris chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, morris.js

I have this morris chart that I would like to refresh using a javascript function. So I then can add a href link on the page that contains that javascript that will refresh the morris chart.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetData")', function (result) {
        Morris.Line({
            element: 'samplechart',
            data: result,
            xkey: 'period',
            ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
            labels: ['YES', 'NO'],
            xLabelAngle: 60,
            parseTime: false,
            resize: true,
            lineColors: ['#32c5d2', '#c03e26']
        });
    });
</script>
```

How would that javascrip funcion look and how do I call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function that initialize your Morris Line Chart without the data: `initMorris`. Then to set the data in your chart, on page load or on link clicked, call the function `getMorris` that gets the data and set the data to the chart `setMorris` using the built-in `setData` function of the Morris Line.

Please try the snippet below (for the example, I created a `getMorrisOffline` function. To get data with ajax, use `getMorris` instead in page load and in the link event onclick):

```js
var morrisLine;
initMorris();
//getMorris(); 
getMorrisOffline();

function initMorris() {
   morrisLine = Morris.Line({
    element: 'samplechart',
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
    labels: ['YES', 'NO'],
    xLabelAngle: 60,
    parseTime: false,
    resize: true,
    lineColors: ['#32c5d2', '#c03e26']
  });
}

function setMorris(data) {
  morrisLine.setData(data);
}

function getMorris() {
  $.get('@Url.Action("GetData")', function (result) {
    setMorris(result);      
  });
}

function getMorrisOffline() {
 var lineData = [
    { period: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { period: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { period: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { period: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { period: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { period: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { period: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ];
  setMorris(lineData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="samplechart"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="getMorrisOffline();">Refresh Morris</a>
```

Comment: how i set ykeys and labels dynamically?

Comment: You can ask a question related to what you tried and where's your problem.